# Invariant subspace for unbounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, unbounded-operators

For a linear bounded operator $T$ on a Hilbert space $H$ that admits an invariant subspace $V$ (meaning: $TV\subset V$), the fact that $T\overline{V}\subset\overline{V}$, where $\overline{V}$ denotes the closure of $V$ in $H$, is a direct consequence of the *continuity* of $T$.

Now I'm wondering up to which extent this can be generalised to unbounded $T$.

Explicitly, I'm asking whether it is true in general that

- if $T$ is a closed, densely defined, unbounded, linear operator $T$ on $H$, with domain $\mathrm{dom}(T)$,
- and if $V\subset\mathrm{dom}(T)\subset H$ is a subspace such that $TV\subset V$,

then also
$$ T ( \mathrm{dom}(T)  \cap \overline{V}) \subset \overline{V}$$

or if instead there are counterexamples to that.

Comment: Closedness of $T$ doesn't work here the same way as boundedness. Pick $x\in\mathrm{dom}(T)\cap \overline{V}$. Then $x$ is the limit in $H$ of a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $V$. If $T$ was bounded, from $x_n\to x$ one deduces $Tx_n\to Tx$, thus concluding that $Tx\in\overline{TV}\subset\overline{V}$. But if $T$ is generically (densely defined, and) closed, the limit $x_n\to x$ is not carried over by $T$. Only if I knew additionally that $(Tx_n)_n$ itself converges, then by closedness $Tx_n\to Tx$, but this cannot be claimed in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be false. Let $H=\ell^2(\Bbb N)$ (with Hilbert basis $e_n$) and define an operator $A$ via

$$A(e_n)=\begin{cases}2^n\,e_n& n>0 \\ 0 & n=0 \end{cases}$$

the domain of this operator is all elements of $\ell^2(\Bbb N)$ that are eventually majorised by $c\,2^{-n}$ for some $c$. Note that $A$ is a closed operator, but its not the operator we are interested in for a counter-example. We will modify it a bit.

Let $x$ be any sequence not majorised by $c\,2^{-n}$ and not having an $e_0$ component, for example $x=\sum_{n>0} \frac1{n^2} \,e_n$. Now let $D(T)= D(A)+\Bbb C\cdot x$ and let $T(x)=e_0$, $T\lvert_{D(A)}=A$.

As the space $V$ we will take the finite linear combinations of the basis vectors $e_n$ for $n>0$. Note that $\overline{V}$ is equal to the orthogonal complement of $e_0$. Next note that $T(V)\subseteq V$, while $x\in \overline{V}$ and $T(x)=e_0\notin\overline V$. That gives you $T(\overline V\cap D(T))\not\subseteq \overline V$. Hence the operator $T$ does not satisfy the conclusion you are looking for, lets see if it satisfies the condition of being closed.

Let $y_n+\lambda_n x$ be a convergent sequence in $D(T)$ so that $T(y_n+\lambda_n x)$ also converges (here $y_n\in D(A)$). What we need to check is that the limit of $y_n+\lambda_n x$ is in $D(T)$ and that $\lim_n T(y_n+\lambda_n x)  = T(\lim_n y_n + \lambda_n x)$. We split into 3 cases, first if $\lambda_n\to0$, second if $\lambda_n$ converges to something non-zero, and third when $\lambda_n$ does not converge.

The first and second case both reduce to the closedness of $A$, while the third case is impossible. This is so, since if $\lambda_n$ converges then convergence of $y_n+\lambda_n x$ is equivalent to convergence of $y_n$ and convergence of $T(y_n+\lambda_n x) = A(y_n)+\lambda_n e_0$ is equivalence to convergence of $A(y_n)$. While if $\lambda_n$ does not converge then (while $y_n+\lambda_n x$ certainly can converge) $T(y_n+\lambda_n x)= A(y_n)+\lambda_n e_0$ has no chance of convering since $A(y_n)\perp e_0$.

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding: for your densely defined $T$ what is the space $V\subset D(T)$ with $TV\subset V$ such that $T(\overline{V}\cap D(T))$ fails to be contained in $\overline{V}$ ? Thanks.

Comment: $V$ should be the sub-space of sequences with finite support. I realise I never actually wrote that.

Comment: I edited the third paragraph to actually refer to the conclusion being violated.

Comment: Oh yes now I see the point very well, thanks. I find your answer now complete, thank you. I'm not an expert, but I've read that there's a whole business about 'invariant subspaces' etc., where apparently normal operators have a special role. It'd be interesting, for example, turning your example into, say, a *self-adjoint* $T$.